# Background image does not fit the actual screen size ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I've been looking for several solutions to this problem, but the solution I found was not enough.

I added the following CSS to the ion-content component:

```css
--background: url ("src / assets / imgs / base.png") no-repeat center center / cover! important;
background-size: 100% 100%! important;
```

However, still, the set background image does not adjust to the device's screen size.
What can I do in this case?